# Nested SQL Statement Yielding Unexpected Results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I am trying to pull registration information based on the level people belong to.  People in level 00 could fit in one of two registrations so I am trying to do a nested case statement.  As the statement stands, I have quite a few people who are showing up in both results of the nested case statement.  All other levels are working fine.  Does anyone have any ideas why a result would appear in both the when and else statement, or is there are more appropriate way to code this instead of nested CASE statements?

```
CASE
        WHEN B.Level = '00' 
        THEN     
                CASE
                    WHEN C.SCREEN = '100' and C.FIELD_NUMBER = '65' and C.FIELD_VALUE = 'Y' THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', B.Level, ':', 'H')
                    ELSE CONCAT(B.Location, ':', B.Level, ':','A')
                END
            WHEN B.Level in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E') THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'A-E')
            WHEN B.Level in ('F', 'G', 'H') THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'F-H')
            WHEN B.Level = 'I' THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'I')
            WHEN B.Level = 'J' THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'J')
            WHEN B.Level = 'K' THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'K')
            ELSE CONCAT(':', B.Location, B.Level) 
END AS Registration,
```

Current Results for a person with a level of 00 who meets the criteria of having the Screen = 100, Field_Number = 65 and Field _Value = Y would result in duplicates such as:

- Person X Location1:Level1:H
- Person X Location1:Level1:A

If Person X meets that criteria then they should not have the second result showing up, or at least that is the result I am going for.

Comment: Regarding the join, is it pulling one value back per "person"?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  In a `case` expression, exactly one `then` clause is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the `case`, the problem is with your `join`.  It is, rightly or wrongly, returning more than one set of values per person duplicated.

If you want to test the efficacy of your `case` expression over a large number of examples, you can try the below:

```
-- Set up some test data:
declare @t table ([Level] nvarchar(10),Screen nvarchar(10), Field_Number nvarchar(10), Field_Value nvarchar(10), [Location] nvarchar(10));
insert into @t values('00','100','65','Y','Location1');

-- Generate 10 rows of the same values:
with t as
(
    select * from @t union all
    select * from @t union all
    select * from @t union all
    select * from @t union all
    select * from @t union all
    select * from @t union all
    select * from @t union all
    select * from @t union all
    select * from @t union all
    select * from @t
), tt as
(   -- And then join them together 6 times to get 1 million rows (10^6):
    select t1.* from t t1, t t2, t t3, t t4, t t5, t t6
)
select CASE
        WHEN B.Level = '00' 
        THEN     
                CASE
                    WHEN b.SCREEN = '100' and b.FIELD_NUMBER = '65' and b.FIELD_VALUE = 'Y' THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', B.Level, ':', 'H')
                    ELSE CONCAT(B.Location, ':', B.Level, ':','A')
                END
            WHEN B.Level in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E') THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'A-E')
            WHEN B.Level in ('F', 'G', 'H') THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'F-H')
            WHEN B.Level = 'I' THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'I')
            WHEN B.Level = 'J' THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'J')
            WHEN B.Level = 'K' THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'K')
            ELSE CONCAT(':', B.Location, B.Level) 
        END AS Registration
    ,count(*) as c
from tt b
group by CASE
        WHEN B.Level = '00' 
        THEN     
                CASE
                    WHEN b.SCREEN = '100' and b.FIELD_NUMBER = '65' and b.FIELD_VALUE = 'Y' THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', B.Level, ':', 'H')
                    ELSE CONCAT(B.Location, ':', B.Level, ':','A')
                END
            WHEN B.Level in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E') THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'A-E')
            WHEN B.Level in ('F', 'G', 'H') THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'F-H')
            WHEN B.Level = 'I' THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'I')
            WHEN B.Level = 'J' THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'J')
            WHEN B.Level = 'K' THEN CONCAT(B.Location, ':', 'K')
            ELSE CONCAT(':', B.Location, B.Level) 
    END
```

The output of this statement is 1 million `Registration` values that are exactly the same: `Location1:00:H`.  If you really wanted to you could make this script return as many values as you like and your `Registration` will not change.

---

To resolve this, do a `select` on just the `join` between your `B` and `C` tables (I hope these are descriptive alias and not just `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` etc?), filtered for `Person X` and see what is returned.  I am 100% confident you will see combinations of data that are different.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was too focused on the case and didn't even think about the join.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: That was the answer I needed so I marked it as such.  Since I am new it doesn't increase the counter.  Thanks again.